# Problem with stepper motor control

Tags: serial, linux, stepper-motor

I am facing a weird problem with my stepper motor when I am trying to control it with my linux computer.

As soon as the serial port is opened from my code to spin the stepper motor, my command terminal starts displaying output in Upper case letters and the output that I get is :

> I HAVE ENTERED THE MAIN LOOPSM,500,0,-400

READLINE: WARNING: TURNING OFF OUTPUT FLUSHING
SAIRAM@GTX:~/OPENCV/TRUNK/OPENCV/SAMPLES/C$

After that,I have to shut down the terminal and start a new terminal screen to control my stepper motor.

I am also attaching the code that talks to the serial port of the computer:

```
    void open_port(char str3[])
{  
  int fd; int n;

  struct termios options;

  /*
   * Get the current options for the port...
   */



  /*
   * Set the baud rates to 19200...
   */

  cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
  cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;
  // options.c_cflag &= ~CNEW_RTSCTS;


  /*
   * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
   */



  /*
   * Set the new options for the port...
   */

  tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW, &options);

  /* File descriptor for the port */


  fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
    {
      /*
       * Could not open the port.
       */

            perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyACM0 - ");
    }
  else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

  //str1
  //strcpy(str1,"EM,0,0");
  strcat(str3,"\r\n");
  printf("%s\n", str3);
  n = write(fd,str3,20);
  if (n < 0)
    fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);



  close(fd);

}
```

I am not a programming expert and hence I could not understand whats going on

Comment: You seem to be using a serial-port stepper driver. What make/model is it? Are you sure it isn't working fine, and your code is just talking to it incorrectly?

Comment: @ Fake: I am using the EI bot board: http://www.schmalzhaus.com/EBB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a termios (and perhaps by association serial) question - there really isn't any relevance to stepper motors other than it being a problem you encountered in the course of talking to a board that happens to drive one.

Most likely the program is adjusting the termios settings for the terminal in addition to for the serial port.  It's probably setting a variety of things, including some lower-to-uppercase translation such as the OLCUC flag or something along those lines.

One solution may be to use tcgetattr to grab a 'backup copy' of the original termios settings into a struct and then use tcsetattr to restore them on exit.

You may be able to recover more ordinary terminal settings after the exit of the program in its current form with stty - for example 'stty sane'

Comment: I tried it in another Linux machine. So I was trying to send commands to the stepper as a set of two. This problem never came up. The same happens in my earlier PC too. I am wondering whether putting the motor control in an infinite loop is a problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the software went bananas. The message is most likely a debug message which they forgot to remove, and which didn't show up during testing, since that part of the code (may be just two lines) should never be executed under normal conditions. That would also explain that you lost your communication.
I call software bug on the EiBotBoard.

Answer (score 0):

I was providing the terminal settings before opening the port. When I changed the code as follows, my problem got resolved:

```
    void open_port(char str3[])
{  
  int fd; int n;

  struct termios options;

  /*
   * Get the current options for the port...
   */

      fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);      

  /*
   * Set the baud rates to 19200...
   */

  cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
  cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;
  // options.c_cflag &= ~CNEW_RTSCTS;


  /*
   * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
   */



  /*
   * Set the new options for the port...
   */



  /* File descriptor for the port */



  if (fd == -1)
    {
      /*
       * Could not open the port.
       */

            perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyACM0 - ");
    }
      else {
   tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW, &options);
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
 }


    char buf[100] = {0};
    strcpy(buf,str3);
    strcat(buf,"\r\n");
    int rc = write(fd,buf,strlen(buf));

  if (rc < 0)
    fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);



  close(fd);

}
```

I have posted the correct code as it might be useful to others as well

Comment: So you were calling tcsetattr with an unitialized fd?  If that happened to be zero or one, it could change the terminal...

Comment: yes... sorry about that